# OpenGL development for mac in Xcode. Can I force software render?

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl

I'm porting an OpenGL game from iPhone to Mac, and having problems with textures getting corrupted. I guess it's a memory problem.

The thing is I've crashed the mac 3 times now (happens random when the game launches), so it's getting difficult to debug this.

Is there any way I can force software render?

[image]

Comment: ah! bad memories. I used to get this screen all the time on my 2007 black macbook. it pissed me off since macs 'never crash'. my new one though really doesn't ever :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select `kCGLRendererGenericID` as `NSOpenGLPFARendererID` when you create the pixelformat attribute list for initing the context ([`initWithAttributes:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLPixelFormat_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOpenGLPixelFormat/initWithAttributes:)).

> **NSOpenGLPFARendererID**
>
> Value is a nonnegative renderer ID number. OpenGL renderers that match the specified ID are preferred. Constants to select specific renderers are provided in the CGLRenderers.h header of the OpenGL framework. Of note is kCGLRendererGenericID which selects the Apple software renderer. The other constants select renderers for specific hardware vendors.

**NOTE!** I just saw that `kCGLRendererGenericID` has been deprecated and the one to use is `kCGLRendererAppleSWID`

Another tip is to start the app with the OpenGL Profiler. See here

http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartzcomposer-dev/2010/Jun/msg00090.html