# kCGLRendererGenericFloatID vs kCGLRendererAppleSWID

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl, gpu, osx-mavericks

What is the difference between kCGLRendererGenericFloatID and kCGLRendererAppleSWID?

The documentation seems very similar, except that kCGLRendererAppleSWID is only supported from 10.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know what renderers are available on your system, you can use code like this:

```
NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attrs[] = {
    NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile, NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core, // optional
    0
};
NSOpenGLPixelFormat* pf = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attrs];
for (int i = 0; i < pf.numberOfVirtualScreens; i++)
{
    GLint val;
    [pf getValues:&val forAttribute:NSOpenGLPFARendererID forVirtualScreen:i];
    val &= kCGLRendererIDMatchingMask;
    printf("renderer 0x%08x\n", val);
}
```

Probably, only one of `kCGLRendererGenericFloatID` or `kCGLRendererAppleSWID` will be available. If both are available, you can query the other attributes of that virtual screen using the same `-getValues:forAttribute:forVirtualScreen:` method to try to distinguish them. You can also create a context and make it current, then query its OpenGL capabilities and limits, as per [OpenGL Programming Guide for Mac: Determining the OpenGL Capabilities Supported by the Renderer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_general/opengl_gen_tasks.html).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately an OpenGL frameworks / driver engineer at Apple is probably the only person who can answer this question for sure but here is some information I've been able to collect.

As you mention, the [relevant part](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGL_OpenGL/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Renderer_IDs) of the CGL documentation implies that any of the following can be used to select a software renderer (depending on your OS version):

- kCGLRendererGenericID (deprecated on OS >= 10.5)
- kCGLRendererGenericFloatID (available in OS >= 10.3)
- kCGLRendererAppleSWID (available in OS >= 10.9)

I've had the following experience with each of these when running OS X 10.10 on Intel HD Graphics 4000:

- kCGLRendererGenericID: This is deprecated for me so it shouldn't be used but it does return a functional context if I ignore the deprecation warnings. I am able to make the resulting context current and render with it without any errors.
- kCGLRendererGenericFloatID: I get a functional context and am able to render with it without any errors.
- kCGLRendererAppleSWID: I am unable to create an NSOpenGLPixelFormat object when I request this renderer so I can't create an NSOpenGLContext object and I can't render.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607097/opengl-development-for-mac-in-xcode-can-i-force-software-render) is somewhat related since it discusses how to force the software renderer.

Answer (score 0):

The book ***OpenGL Programming on Mac OS X: Architecture, Performance, and Integration*** describes this in chapter 6, "*Selecting a Renderer*":

> The star of this show is the Apple software renderer, which was
>   released as part of Tiger. If you wish to use or test certain
>   functionality that your hardware doesn’t support, you can use this
>   renderer. This software renderer is specified using
>   `kCGLRendererGenericFloatID`. You may hear this renderer described as “the float 
>   renderer” because of its support for floating-point framebuffers and
>   pixel formats. This software renderer is highly tuned for the Mac
>   platform. It uses a great deal of hand-tuned and hand-scheduled
>   PowerPC and Intel assembly. The performance of this renderer, though
>   not comparable to that of a dedicated hardware renderer, is quite
>   astonishing.
>
> `kCGLGenericID` corresponds to the original software
>   renderer written for OS X. If you are experiencing difficulty with the
>   new software renderer and your application doesn’t use features beyond
>   OpenGL 1.2, you may have better luck with this original renderer.
>   Although not as highly tuned, the old software renderer is better
>   tested by virtue of its age alone.
>
> `kCGLRendererAppleSWID`
>   Arguably, this renderer ID should not be published. It serves as a placeholder
>   (and a questionable one at that) for graphics driver writers for OS X.

The Apple [Core GL reference](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGL_OpenGL/CGL_OpenGL.pdf) has this to say about `kCGLGenericID`:

> Specifies the software renderer. Deprecated on Intel-based Macintosh computers.